# How to write the Jasmine unit test case for IFrame

Tags: karma-jasmine

As I am writing angularJS Jasmine test case for iframe print, but it showing "Cannot read property 'open' of undefined". Please find below the snippet of the code

```
Source code:

$scope.print = function() {
    var iFrame = document.getElementById("printingFrame"); 
    var iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentDocument; 
    iFrameDoc.open();
    var contents = "text";
    iFrameDoc.write(contents);
    iFrameDoc.close();
    iFrame.contentWindow.focus(); 
    iFrame.contentWindow.print();
};

Test Case:

describe("just a test", function () {
    it("should print iframe content", function () {
       locals.$scope.print();
    });
});

Error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

Anyone know why the following unit test does not pass?

Comment: You have to test for a mockup assertion like expect(print).toHaveBeenCalled()

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I'm accessing contentWindow from test and it is 'null', but in the browser it works fine.

Comment: @MakerDrone, try looking at this: 
https://davidwalsh.name/iframe-contentwindow-null

Comment: @Orion's link gave me the fix... that should be added as an answer for this question